# Are Mathematics the language of the universe?

Tags: soft-question, education

I am a high school student and next year i am going to be a physics major, so this year i put all my effort on physics and mathematics, since it a great tool for physicists.

But now i wonder, in creating a new physics theorem , can we rely solely on mathematics? I mean have there ever been published theorems that are mathematically valid but do not apply in the real world? / Is a mathematically valid model necessarily a real model, or a theorem is only proven by experimental data?

Comment: Obviously, virtually *all* possible mathematical theorems that are true do *not* apply to the real world. This doesn't rule out the fact that there are still a *gazillion* theorems that *are* relevant. Finding out which one is relevant is, in the end, a matter of experiment. Anyhow, I'm voting to close since this question is about philosophy of science (and probably too opinion-based as well).

Comment: Someone once, said to me: "You have the problem. And you have the final solution. Anything that you do in the middle, it is valid"  =)

Comment: *"I mean have there ever been published theorems that are mathematically valid but do not apply in the real world?"* Yes. The field that deals with those that never apply is called mathematics. The field that deals with those that may be found to apply is called theoretical physics (research).

Comment: To the Curious Mind: Why do you say so? (So low is your opinion on mathematics?) The Riemann geometry is not applied in physics? Historically, it first was just a mathematical game, but then it became a physically applied theory. (Mathematics departments wouldn't be given money if there weren't the hope that a mathematical development, today only on paper, could be tomorrow something applicable.)

Comment: This seems like a list-type question which is considered off-topic. Could you reformulate your question so as to not be so dependent on a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. When we build a theory we start from a couple of assumptions that we BELIEVE that are valid, i.e. in the everyday life, and/or in previous experiments, they were confirmed. From this point we use mathematics and obtain other results. As long as we need our new results for proving even more theorems, things may be fine. But a physical theory is worth NOTHING if not experimentally confirmed.
And if the experiment says otherwise than our theory, we begin to look which assumption may be incorrect.

We have all the time such problems in building theories (models) for describing the world. In the microscopic world (atoms, electrons, protons, etc.) we have bad surprises. And it is not simple to clarify them, because these tiny particles are so delicate that our measurements disturb them.
In trying models of the universe we also have problems. And it is difficult to elucidate because information that we get from galaxies, tells us what happened with them an enormous time ago.

So, prepare yourself, the life of a physicist is not roses (but it is a great challenge).

Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

Newton described his theories with maths, and they worked great, until Einstein came along and found that as objects approached the speed of light, Newwton's maths broke down.

Empirical evidences trumps theory.

Comment: until you get the final theory